# Почему первый цикл не запускается снова?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Switch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean key = true;
        while (key) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Введи возраст или Exit для завершения программы");
            String age = scanner.nextLine();
            if (age.equals("exit")){
                key = false;
            } else {
                switch (age) {
                    case "ноль":
                        System.out.println("Ты родился");
                        break;
                    case "семь":
                        System.out.println("Ты пошол в школу");
                        break;
                    case "восемнадцать":
                        System.out.println("Ты закончи школу");
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Не одно из условий не подошло");
                }
            }
        }
       System.out.println("Программа закрыта");

      while (key==false) {
          System.out.println("Для запуска программы введите start");
          Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
          String start = scn.nextLine();
          if (start.equals("start")) {
              key = true;
              System.out.println("Ошибка");
          } else {
              System.out.println("Программа не запущена");
          }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Перенесите второй цикл внутрь первого.

Comment: Спасибо так все работает, а все же почему если циклы отдельно первый не стартует снова?

Comment: @Slaxor не стартует снова потому, что код выполняется линейно сверху вниз..... блок `while` работает пока `true`...именно поэтому надпись `"Программа закрыта"` никогда не появится если цикл будет постоянно крутиться..... как только становится `false`, то цикл отработал все и выполнение  кода идет дальше по строкам, и никогда больше вверх не поднимается.